# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2014 due to an error

Tags: database-connection, windows-10, sql-server-2014

I want to install SQL Server on my machıne whıch has Windows 10 operating system. When I use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to SQL Server, then I get this error:

[image]

I make firewall settings. And the server is running now as follows.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" default instance is **stopped** - so therefore you cannot connect to `.` or `(local)`.

You do have a "SQL Server (SQL2014)" instance up and running, so try using `.\SQL2014` or `(local)\SQL2014` for connection ....

You need to use `.\SQL2014` and not just `SQL2014` ..... the syntax is either just `machinename`, or then `machinename\instancename` -so if your instance is `SQL2014`, you need to use `.\SQL2014` (or `machine\SQL2014`) to connect to it.

You're using `SQL2014` which means, SQL Server is searching for a **server machine** by the name of `SQL2014` and trying to connect to its default instance - which obviously fails.